# Code in inspect element cannot be found

Tags: css, html, navigation

So I've been scratching my head for the last two hours over this little issue. I can see the HTML code in inspect element.

But cannot find it anywhere. I've looked at all the files including the css, javascript and also sass files. Is there a method on the inspect elements that can accurately show me the code file? So far is seems to think it's in the index.html file..

Looking forward to your responses

Comment: will you elaborate ?

Comment: what browser is it? it varies a bit where the "stuff" is shown

Comment: the answer is no, you can use html grep or windows wingrep to search for a particular keyword and try to find the code that execute that html element. If even grep can't find it, its in the DB.

Comment: If the particular HTML does not show in View/Page Source (so it isn't present in the core page download) and isn't in a frame, then it must be dynamically added via Javascript somehow.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. 

It's a HTML5 Up template that I grabbed and started playing around with. Basically it has a responsive drop-down menu, that I can't seem to access outside of inspect element. The main navigation is of course in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the code does not exist in the source, it might have been generated on the fly with javascript, or the content might have been generated server side, possibly from a DB. If its a case of malformed html (no closing tags etc), it might also have been generated by the browser itself.

If you give us more info on whats not showing we might help to determine where it originates from. Is it inline CSS? Is it an article? Is it appearing from clicking other stuff?

EDIT: To answer you question *"Is there a method on the inspect elements that can accurately show me the code file?"* No, there isnt, it can come from the above mentioned methods or other, and since youre not sharing the actual case all we can do to help is keep guessing

Comment: Basically it has a responsive drop-down menu, that I can't seem to access outside of inspect element. Unfortunately I cannot upload an image yet.

Comment: @FarazJafari the dropdown could be generated from some type of data-model in JS. Try to look for the words in the source (or it could be fetched with ajax) were really shooting in the dark here since you wont share more

Comment: To be honest I don't know what else to share?
Will look over the javascript code again to see if I can find anything.

Comment: well, you could share the template you are using (and mentioned above) or even better, if your project is public share a link to that. Or if you want the problem solved - make the project public. Further you could share the part of the code where the HTML should be, and share the part that you see in you browser that you are looking for - i could go on

Comment: Thanks Zedd will keep these in mind in the future.

I've managed to find it. It was located the in main.js file.

`code` (

// Navigation Panel.
    $(
     '<div id="navPanel">' +
      '<nav>' +
       '<a href="index.html" class="link depth-0">HOME</a>' +
       $('#nav').navList() +
      '</nav>' +
     '</div>'
    )

)

`code`

I had seen it before, but didn't occur to me that it was it, was looking for something that resembled the navigation ul li html code.

PS I have no idea how to show the code correctly ahhaha